# Xcode NSLog text format and UITextView text format

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

In my current xcode program I have been able to add a `.rpt` file (report file) and was able to display it in `NSLog` and it looks like the following (minus the periods).

First............Line1

Second......Line2

Third..........Line3

Forth..........Line4

Fifth...........Line5

As you can everything is lining up. But when I add the text into a `uitextview` it looks like this:

First   Line1

Second      Line2

Third  Line3

Forth     Line4

Fifth    Line5

As you can see nothing is lining up correctly. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

the console font is != the textview font. the console font is monospaced. it is Menlo Regular, 11pt

SO

change the textview's font (make it monospaced if you wanna copy the console's output)

Comment: Thanks I'll change the font and post back the results.

Comment: Changing the font has worked perfectly, thank you!  its blows my mind when you spend hours trying to figure this out while the solution being so simple.  Now to add to this can you separate every line by monospace into an array?

Comment: `NSArray* array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];`